# MVC5 Add Item to List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Given a Model of :

```
public class Receipt: BaseEntity
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "Please Select A Store")]
    public Store  Store { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Item NewItem { get; private set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage = "ReceiptModel.EntryDate is required")]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public Guid EntryOwner { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double ReceiptTotal()
    {
        return Items.Sum(item => item.ItemPrice);
    }
    public Receipt()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
        EntryOwner = Guid.Empty;
        EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        Store = new Store();
        NewItem = new Item();
     }       
}
```

And a Controller :

```
public class ReceiptController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Receipt/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
        return View(receipt);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddItem(Receipt receipt)
    {
        receipt.Items.Add(receipt.NewItem);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", receipt);
        }
        return View("Index", receipt);
    }
```

And a View: **Updated View - Removed all partial pages and combined into a single page**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="@Url.Action("AddItem","Receipt")">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="main" class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading"> <h1 class="panel-title">Receipt Builder</h1></div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <fieldset>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Store.Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Store.Name)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EntryDate)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EntryDate)
            </fieldset>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">#</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Item</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Unit</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">UnitPrice</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Category</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="control-label">Total</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

                <td>
                    <button class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: red;" name="Submit" id="Submit" type="submit">+</button>
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Name)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.UnitType)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Quantity)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.UnitPrice)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Category.Name)<br/>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.Category.IsTaxable)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewItem.ItemPrice)
                </td>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.Items.ToList().IndexOf(item) + 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.UnitType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.UnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.Category.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(titem => item.ItemPrice)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Seeing as my answer didn't solve it: can you share the code of the `ItemList` partial view? I notice there's some Ajax as well, can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I actually removed the Ajax piece after your suggestion so there is only a single form on on the page now. I have also added the requested/applicable partialviews

Comment: Just a thought: try putting your `newItem` generation in a separate partial view as well. As it is right now, it might not be able to bind the input fields to the actual `newItem` object, since that's merely a field inside the current model. You can call it with `@Html.Partial("_addItem", new Item())`. Could you perhaps expand on your exact steps taken to determine the fault, should this not work?

Comment: So when I submit the newItem obj is populated correctly so I believe that binding is fine. However the List<Item> is always empty. I have tried moving things around to their own partial views. originally this started with a single view. I am pretty close to setting the receipt object inside of the session state. I had it working that way before but that doesnt follow the MVC pattern very well...

Comment: In that case I have no further idea. Sidenote though: using sessions won't violate the MVC pattern. It will make your application stateful though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this thanks to [This Link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

It was indeed a binding issue as was suggested. It seems that with complex collections such as Lists we cannot actually utilize the benefits of IEnumerable like I had hoped. This is due to how the data is actually passed in the post having names that are ambiguous. Here is the final code that is working (only have to update the view)

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                @(i+1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].UnitType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].UnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].Category.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.Items[i].ItemPrice
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

The resulting HTML names each element with its index ie Item[N].Name
Now the post data can be bound correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Items from your Receipt are shows just as text, without controls. So when you post data back to server ASP.NET MVC can't find this information from request body and lefts Receipt.Items collection empty.

You may add information about entered receipts as hidden fields in partial view with help of Html.HiddenFor() method. Or just save entered items in DB or somewhere else and read theirs into Receipt.Items collection before returning AddItem view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The NewItem property is getting passed in with all the correct values but the property List<Item> is getting passed in as empty every time.

Comment: Yep, you're right. NewItem property value has been composed from editors, which you've added with Html.EditorFor methods. But for Items collection no data exists in your form, so after posting data back to the server this collection empty.
Let's make small sample. Just replace Html.EditorFor calls in your Receipt Builder fieldsed by Html.LabelFor, add some default data into your Receipt in Index action and see the result after submitting form back. Your Receipt data will also be empty after postback.

Comment: Your answer ultimately led me down the path I needed to go, thank you.